# How to make a div take the whole width of the browser window without overlapping elements

Tags: html, css, width, overlapping

I've encountered a problem. I want to make a div with gallery->PICTURES take the whole width of the page. I tried with

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

and it works, but elements and pages are now overlapping...how would I solve this problem?

Link to my page: http://web.ntf.uni-lj.si/~mojcaovnic/

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code here. A link isn´t as persistant as it should be. SO wants solutions for everyone, not only for you, some your problem may help someone else.

Comment: plz add the html and css for that part. I coudn't recognize which div u are trying.

Comment: add some code or create a jsfiddle with what you try to do and where you are stuck so we can see what you are trying to do. From what you said the only thing I understand is you want to do: div{width:100%;}

Comment: Make sure that the parent element has a position property value of relative. That will help hold it withing.

Comment: surely it would have taken 2 minutes to find the answer to this online ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:absolute;` means it will no longer use any space within the document, which is why your elements are overlapping. You should use `position:relative;` to avoid this.

Using `width:100vw;` will give the div the full width of your viewport and using `width:100%;` will give it the width of its parent element.